# SOAP request in a while loop

Tags: python, django, soap

I am developing a service where the user need to sign the seller agreement with Mobile BankID (Swedish e-sign service). To make this work I need to make SOAP request to get the progress status of the signing request in Mobile BankID.

Is this code understandable? How can I make it more clean?

```
def collect_request(transaction_id):
    '''You can make a delay for 9 seconds before you start to call the Collect
    method. After 9s you begin to make CollectRequest with a 3 seconds delay
    between each collect. First answer will probably be
    OUTSTANDING_TRANSACTION, then USER_SIGN and at last COMPLETE. (After six
    OUTSTANDING_TRANSACTION you get NO_CLIENT, just to indicate that the user
    not yet has started her BankID client.

    After 180 seconds, you will at last get faultStatus EXPIRED_TRANSACTION'''
    time.sleep(9)
    seller_agreement = SellerAgreement.objects.get(id=transaction_id)
    url = '<WSDL URL HERE>'
    client = Client(url)

    val = 'OUTSTANDING_TRANSACTION'
    while True:
        try:
            response = client.service.Collect(policy='logtest001',
                                              provider='bankid',
                                              displayName='Test av Mobilt BankID',
                                              transactionId=transaction_id,
                                              orderRef=seller_agreement.order_ref)
            print response
            if response.progressStatus != val:
                trigger_new_sign_event(seller_agreement.user.id, response.progressStatus)
                val = response.progressStatus
            if (response.progressStatus == 'OUTSTANDING_TRANSACTION' or response.progressStatus == 'USER_SIGN' or response.progressStatus == 'NO_CLIENT'):
                # Try again in 3 seconds
                time.sleep(3)
                continue
            if response.progressStatus == 'COMPLETE':
                # TODO: Save to db
                print "Done!"
            break
        except WebFault, f:
            print f  # Django log?
            trigger_new_sign_event(seller_agreement.user.id, f.fault.faultstring)
            # TODO: cancelled_at?
            break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This docstring is very long and confusing. The official Python style guide recommends that you have a short one line summary of what the function does before launching into longer, detailed paragraphs.

```
def collect_request(transaction_id):
    '''Waits while collecting a mobile bank ID request.

    You can make a delay for 9 seconds before you start to call the Collect
    method. After 9s you begin to make CollectRequest with a 3 seconds delay
    between each collect. First answer will probably be
    OUTSTANDING_TRANSACTION, then USER_SIGN and at last COMPLETE. (After six
    OUTSTANDING_TRANSACTION you get NO_CLIENT, just to indicate that the user
    not yet has started her BankID client.

    After 180 seconds, you will at last get faultStatus EXPIRED_TRANSACTION'''
```

I'm not sure I got it quite right, so I'm sure you can come up with a better one. Also there's not much need for using `url` as a variable directly before it's used 'when you can pass it directly to `Client`. Though it should either be a constant defined elsewhere or a user provided parameter. There's a lot of values like that in here. Making something a constant makes it clearer what the value means, where it comes from and what it's for.

```
WSDL_URL = "some url"
PROVIDER = "bankid"
```

etc.

Your third `if` should actually be an `elif`, since the second and third conditions are mutually exclusive. You should then remove the `continue` and instead manually call `break` from inside your `if response.progressStatus == 'COMPLETE'` block. It makes more sense that way, that your loop breaks when this condition is fulfilled, rather than the `continue` being called in certain other cases. Unless you want to break even if any unhandled `progressStatus` value is received. ie. As it stands, if `progressStatus` is anything but `'OUTSTANDING_TRANSACTION', 'USER_SIGN' or 'NO_CLIENT'` then the loop breaks. If that *is* intentional, then you should comment as such.

Also don't use the old syntax for exceptions, it's ambiguous and explicitly doesn't work in Python 3. You should use `except WebFault as f`. The reason it's ambiguous is that it doesn't allow you to do multiple exceptions properly, imagine you had to try do `except WebFault, ValueError, f`. It wouldn't make any sense, however you could do `except (WebFault, ValueError) as f` perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this code is nicely readable.

This condition can be simplified:

> ```
> if (response.progressStatus == 'OUTSTANDING_TRANSACTION' or response.progressStatus == 'USER_SIGN' or response.progressStatus == 'NO_CLIENT'):
> ```

By using a tuple of the states:

```
status_to_try_again = ('OUTSTANDING_TRANSACTION', 'USER_SIGN', 'NO_CLIENT')
if response.progressStatus in status_to_try_again:
```

It might be a good idea to move these string literals to constants at the top of the file.